# Can an x86 executable run on any x86 platform given the right runtime libraries?

Tags: c++, windows, x86, executable, compiled

While I did find similar-ish questions, they did not really answer this specific question.

Can a compiled x86 executable run on any x86 platform given the right runtime libraries?
Say I make a C++17 program *without dependencies*, could I run this program on Windows 95 or is there some sort of support required by the OS?

I also heard that RTTI (in the case of C++) may not be supported everywhere, is this only due to the processor having to support this feature or does the OS play a role in that? This would imply that new features would maybe not be supported by, e.g., Windows 95.

### Edit

What I'm after is whether an executable (e.g., x86) can run on any platform supporting that instruction set or wether certain features, like RTTI, need specific OS support and thus are not available on all platforms supporting that instruction set.

Comment: @Ðаn I better specified the question. I mean a compiled executable

Comment: I saw someone use C++14 to write pong for a commodore 64.  What you need to a compiler that can build for the target machine.

Comment: No it will likely not work on an incompatible OS. Unless it can run in some type of emulation container. Same goes for an incompatible CPU.

Comment: @Ðаn I imagine that the C-goers also tire of seeing `cout` and `using namespace std;` in their queue.

Comment: @Ðаn I'm still new to C++ so please correct me if I'm wrong but I mean a compiled executable written in a compiled language like C++ or C that consists of machine code

Comment: ***I also heard that RTTI may not be supported everywhere, is this only due to the processor having to support this feature or does the OS play a role in that?*** This is compiler support.

Comment: @Ðаn Well, I'm the curious kinda guy

Comment: @drescherjm So does RTTI support only depend on the compiler? What are things that need OS and/or CPU support?

Comment: Why does this question get so many downvotes by the way? It is an important question for a new-comer, especially a Java, "build once run anywhere" guy

Comment: ***CPU support*** Think of this: if you have a MIPS executable that is not going to run on an x86 processor (without some emulation).

Comment: @drescherjm That makes sense, but I was more talking about an x86 executable on Windows

Comment: You should have tagged your question to indicate that.

Comment: I updated the question to make more sense

Comment: To be fair, your question is a reasonable one, if you are asking if you can take a compiled program without "dependencies" from one x86 platform to another. It isn't necessarily _obvious_ that you can't, and indeed in the past some minimal type of interop like this _was_ possible between different platforms. You might want to make the focus of your question the idea of a compiled binary, and use only C and C++ as examples of how such a binary might be generated, to skirt the wrath of the langauge lawyers who'll tell you this isn't defined in the standard, etc, etc.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Actually, it slowly became a reasonable one. See the edit history.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - fair enough, I gathered various surgeries had already been performed here :)

Comment: @Ðаn It's irrelevant how many platforms "C programs" run on. It's just about whether compiled executables have the same "build once, run anywhere (with the right runtime)" qualities that Java has (which it apparently _really_ does not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general **you cannot**, even if you restricted your universe to x86 hardware - at least not without some conversion of the binary or some platform-specific "loader" for each target platform.

For exmaple a typical binary emitted by a C or C++ compiler<sup>1</sup> will have some minimal dependency on the OS and runtime, for example to load and do runtime linking on the executable. Different platforms have different binary formats (such as [PE/COFF on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) or [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) across various UNIX flavors and Linux) and there isn't any common "x86 format" that would work *directly* on any platform.

Furthermore, any non-trivial program and in many cases *any* program, trivial or not, is going to have platform-specific dependencies on the the langauge runtime. For example, even an empty `main()` function often requires runtime support to get from the OS-defined "start" method to the main method, and without unusual build options there are often calls at startup to initialize parts of the standard library.

Finally, as you alluded to with your comment about RTTI, various language or platform features may essentially be compiled into the binary and require OS support. RTTI probably doesn't *obviously* fall into this category, but things like position-independent code, thread-local storage and stack-unwinding support for exception handling often do. The compiled x86 code that uses such features may be *quite different* on different platforms since it needs to build in assumptions of how those work.

In principle, however, you could *imagine* this working, at least for some limited subset of programs. For example, while the various executable formats are in practice incompatible, they aren't *that* different and [tools exist](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) to convert between them. So you could certainly implement a minimal runtime on your platform of interest that takes an x86 executable compiled to whatever fixed format you choose and converts at runtime to the local format and runs it.

Beyond that actually trying to map even standard library calls would be quite difficult since different operating systems using different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), but it could be possible for "C" functions using some thunks to put things in the right place. C++ is pretty much right out because the ABI there is much more complex, compiler-and-platform specific and much of the implementation detail is already compiled-in for stuff implemented in headers.

In fact, the idea that (a subset of) x86 might provide a interesting intermediate language for cross-platform execution is exactly the idea behind exploited in Google's [NaCl project]. Essentially, the NaCl runtime provides platform agnostic "loading" capabilities which allow x86 code to run more-or-less natively on various platforms. Subsequently other native formats such as ARM were added, but it started as an x86 sandbox. A large part of the project deals with running code that provably safe (i.e., sandboxed) - but it shows that with some infrastructure you can write "portable" x86. A standard C or C++ compiler isn't going to emit NaCl compatible code directly, however.

---

<sup>1</sup> Really, *any* compiler that compiles to a native format. I just call out C and C++ since they seem like the ones you are interested in and are widely familiar.

Answer (score 3):

This question misses the point. C++ is, first and foremost, a language to describe the **behaviour** of a computer program.

Using a compiler to create a native binary executable file to *produce* that behaviour on an actual computer is the typical way of using the language.

Once you have the binary file, all traces of the source code used to produce it are gone (unless you have built a special version for debugging purposes). The compatibility of the binary file with specific hardware or operating systems is beyond the scope of C++ itself.

The same is true for C, or any other programming language which typically gets compiled to native binary code.

Or, to answer the question more briefly:

> Can compiled C++/C code (i.e. an executable) run anywhere given the right runtime libraries?

No.

Comment: I don't feel like this answers the question. I know that after compiling an executable all traces of the source language are gone. I just want to know whether a compiled executable requires support from the OS for certain features (like RTTI) or whether it only needs the right runtime libraries

Comment: @itzJanuary: Yes, I agree the answer is a bit off-topic for the question as it is now; it was more valid for the *original* question before all the edits. It's still basically correct and it has received some upvotes, which means someone has found it to be valuable in some way, so I'll leave it here and not delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a compiled x86 executable run anywhere given the right runtime libraries?

No, it will only work on x86 hardware, or other hardware (or software, such as a virtual machine) that emulates the x86 instruction set (such as a x64 CPU).  In practice, that's very likely to be a far cry from "anywhere."

And even if the hardware matches, an x86 executable will have operating system dependencies.  A Windows binary won't run on Linux, even if the hardware is the same.  There are various strategies that can make things like this "work" in some situations, Microsoft's [Linux Subsystem for Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/) is one recent example which allows Linux binaries to run unchanged on Windows.  Again, a fry cry from "anywhere."